# Scroll to element ID if ng-model is true AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a page where I display a list (result of a search input).

I'm using a `ng-model` to capture the input text: `ng-model="search_text"`.

Thing is that I want to autoscroll to the div containing the list every time the model has something. If it is empty it should do nothing, but if something is written in the `search_text` it should do the trick and auto-scroll down to the list results.

Comment: you can use `ng-style`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with a simple directive like in this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gc2kjtuf/)**. It uses [`$anchorScroll()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) to implement a auto-scroll feature.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="searchText" type="text">
  <div id="list" auto-scroller id-to-scroll-to="'list'" trigger="searchText">
     My List
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application / directive

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {});

myApp.directive('autoScroller', function ($location, $anchorScroll, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrit: 'A',
      scope: {
        trigger: '=',
        idToScrollTo: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('trigger', function (newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
            $timeout(function () {
              $location.hash(scope.idToScrollTo);
              $anchorScroll();
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I make it work only when the submit button of the input is pressed?

Comment: @AbielMuren Yea sure, just try `ng-click="searchText = true"` or use an other scope param as trigger.